# How to select many diagram symbols of tables from search results?

Tags: powerdesigner

After doing some sophisticated search of tables with several criterias (part of name, specific stereotype, etc.) and got result list of many tables. It's not clear how to select all of them at once on diagram (for example to group them, or move to separate space, or apply the same format for all of them like background color)?

The only things we could do with results looks like are limited with "Find in diagram" for a single selected table. Is it possible somehow to workaround this limitation, and be able to "Select in diagram all (or several multiselected) tables" from search result list ?

PS: using PowerDesigner 16.5 SP3 at Physical Model mode.

PPS: the current workaround is doing a serch by Vbscripts coding, and also manipulating symbols format from VBScripts. It's rather inconvinient to write code for simple GUI manipulations, which could be done manualy for selected objects. I hope for better workaround...

Comment: That's a good one... Even using scripting, I can't seem to find a way to do it: the existing `ActiveSelection` is read-only, and it seems impossible to get the list of found objects...

Comment: I heard that `BaseModel.CreateSelection()` and the methods of
`ObjectSelection` and maybe `PersistentSelection` could somehow be used for creating a new selection, but I don't have much experience with VBscript

Comment: CreateSelection() creates a PersistentSelection, which can be used to limit the generation, or reporting... to some objects. On one side, these selections are not related with the results of the Find; on the other, they are not related with the symbols selection in a diagram...